# Regex: extracting keys/values from string

Tags: regex

I have hundreds of lines with the following format

```
00008#A=1#B=3334#C=23/03A#D=BA FRCT TL4 3/4-5/6 US#AVC=DD 2
```

Keys start with `#`, the line above is then :

```
A=1
B=3334
C=23/03A
D=BA FRCT TL4 3/4-5/6 US
AVC=DD 2
```

The line have many different/more keys and values.

The goal is to extract the keys and values.

Using ruby, without regex, I can do:

```
line.split("#")[1..-1].inject({}) do |hash, kv|
  k, v = kv.split('=')
  hash[k] = v
  hash
end
```

Which outputs:

```
{"A"=>"1", "B"=>"3334", "C"=>"23/03A", "D"=>"BA FRCT TL4 3/4-5/6 US", "AVC"=>"DD 2"}
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same in regex, since a line can have dozens of key/values with different value lengths.

My starting point is : ([A-Z])\w+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regexp will match one `#key=value`:

```
#([^=]+)=([^#]*)
```

Use a function that returns all the matches. The capture groups in each match will be the key and value, respectively.